# Jest/Enzyme | Test a mask/unmask Password function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a form, in my react component, that has 2 fields that call a function, that on click `show button` masks and unmasks the specific fields. Basically, I need some help on how to test the function itself.

The Function:

```
  togglePasswordMask = e => {
    const { type } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      passwordIsMasked: !prevState.passwordIsMasked,
      type: type === 'password' ? 'input' : 'password'
    }));
  };
```

I call that function, in my render method like this:

```
<div className="input-group mb-3">
  <Field
        type={type}
        className={classNames('form-control', {
       'is-invalid': errors.password && touched.password
     })}
     placeholder="Password (Required)"
     name="password"
   />
   <div className="input-group-append">
   <span className="input-group-text">
   <div
    className={type === 'password' ? 
   'fa fa-eye fa-lg' : 'fa fa-eye-slash fa-lg'}
   onClick={this.togglePasswordMask}
   />
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

It also has an INITIAL_STATE:

```
  state = {
    type: 'password',
    groups: []
  };
```

**Can you help me, write the test cases for this, using Jest and Enzyme.** I tried the following, but they don't seem to work:

```
  describe('UserCreateForm TogglePassword', () => {
    it('Should unmask password and confirmPassword on click', () => {
      const maskElement = wrapper.find('.fa fa-eye fa-lg');
      const maskFn = maskElement.simulate('click');
      expect(maskFn().state()).toEqual('input');
    });
  });
```

I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`.

I iterated a little bit after I found another answer, and my test now looks something like this:

```
    it('Should unmask password and confirmPassword on click', () => {
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
      const maskElement = wrapper.find('.fa-eye');
      const maskFn = maskElement.simulate('click', {
        preventDefault: () => {}
      });
      expect(maskFn().state()).toEqual('input');
    });
```

And now, I get another error: `maskFn, is not a function`.

Comment: I also, added in maskFn, `jest.fn()`, `jest.mock()` and `jest.spyOn()`, but with no luck. Different erros all regarding jest itself.

Comment: why do you referring to internal state as `expect(maskFn().state())` in first place? you can just `expect(wrapper.find(Field).props().type).toEqual('input')`

Answer (score 0):

your immediate problem is because `maskElement.simulate` returns `Self` according to the [Enzyme docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html), and that's an object not a function.  Get rid of `maskFn` completely, call `maskElement.simulate` and ignore its return value, and just run your `expect` against `maskElement.state()`.

(Also, instead of testing against your component's internal state - which some feel to be an anti-pattern because you're testing component implementation and not component behavior - consider `expect`ing the component to render a `<Field type="password" />` vs a `<Field type="text" />`)

Comment: So, I tried this, but it is still failing:
`TypeError: maskElement is not a function

      73 |         preventDefault: () => {}
      74 |       });
    > 75 |       expect(maskElement('FormikConnect(FieldInner)').get(3).props.type).toBe(
         |              ^
      76 |         <Field type="input" />
      77 |       );
      78 |     });

      at Object.it (src/admin/management/users/components/UserCreateForm/__tests__/index.test.jsx:75:14)`